# How to check if a software is legitimate

Tags: threats

if I have a developer who wants to install a new software and he ask me to check this software security before installing it what shall I do

Comment: You might be asking one (or more) of many different questions here. I'll try and briefly answer as many as I can below, but you will get better answers if you edit the question to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 8):

You could be asking one of many questions here.

- If you are asking "How do I know that the software I have here is
  what the vendor made - could it have been altered before I got it?"
  then you will want to compare the hash of what you have to what the
  vendor has published, assuming they have. (Almost everyone does
  nowadays.)
- If you are asking "How can I tell if the vendor has put malware or
  back doors into this software?" then the key thing to consider is how
  much you trust the vendor. (Although that's not a guarantee. Big
  companies have accidentally gotten a virus on their gold masters
  before now, and the bigger you are, the more likely a government is
  to lean on you to put a back door in.) Of course you've scanned it
  with a couple of AV scanners, like you do with anything you put on
  your network. Talk to other users and see if they have any issues. If
  it's open source, you can read the source before compiling, although
  that is a huge amount of work. Lastly, you can run it in a sandbox
  for a while, monitoring what it does, especially it's network
  activity to see if it phones home.
- If you are asking "How can I tell if it has programming mistakes
  that make it vulnerable to attack?" then again there are various
  approaches. As before, consider the reputation of the vendor; talk to other users; and if it's open
  source and you have the resources, review the source. Check it's
  bug tracking system if this is public, and it's historical release
  notes, to see how well security issues are addressed. Think about
  what it does and what threats you face, and identify other security
  controls you can put around it.

Comment: that is what I was looking for, after 3 years I have learnt most of things you mentioned here, Thank You sir

Answer (score 2):

(Liked the Graham Hill approach to answer):

One more question/answer you could think about:

- If you are asking "What I want to protect if the software isn't trustworthy?" then you might consider that you could install the software in a virtual machine that doesn't have connection with your network, so that a vulnerability wouldn't be able to get data from other computers, for example. And even if the user puts some "secret" data in the program, it won't be able to send it out.

Comment: trustfull --> trustworthy?